# NumberFormat percentage displayed in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a simple loan calculating system in Java. I ran into the problem with calculation currency format I entered on the interest percentage 2 on the textfield, but it is displayed as 200.00% this format, why I don't know. What I tried so far I  attached below.

```
 NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
 double   interset = Double.parseDouble(txtInterest.getText());
 txtMonth2.setText(percent.format(interset));
```

I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: If you want 2% then the value that you are formatting has to be 0.02, not 2.

Comment: if i enter the percentage  2 on the textfield how to calculate as 0.02 automatally

Comment: interset = Double.parseDouble(percent.format(txtInterest.getText())); i wrote like this way but not working

Comment: Multiply the double you parse from the `JTextArea` by 0.01;

Comment: can you write code so easy to understandable

Answer (score 1):

When you see a percentage with the % sign, the value is generally a number to be divided by 100 (that's the case for Java, C, Excel...):

- In your problem, 200% means you entered 2 (200 / 100 = 2).
- 2% is in fact 2 / 100 = 0.02 (

Either you use the value as 0.02 directly, either you divide it when formatting; the former being easier.

On a side note, you could use [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) instead:

```
JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter editFormatter = new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
 JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter displayFormatter = new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(
                 displayFormatter, displayFormatter, editFormatter);
JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(factory );
ftf.setValue(0.50); // 50%
```

The example is adapted from the Java and javadoc tutorial found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#factory

This will handle the formatting issue for you and you will only have to provide a valid percentage.